# realloc array of pointers

Tags: c, realloc

This is part of my program. `parameters.path` is a string that contains a path to the file I will be working with, but that is not in this code.

```
typedef struct directory {

   char *name;
   char *path;

} directory;

void insertDir(directory*** array , char * path, char* name, int* length) {

    directory *p = malloc(sizeof(directory));

    p->path = malloc(strlen(path)+ 1);
    strcpy(p->path, path);

    p->name = malloc(strlen(name)+ 1);
    strcpy(p->name, name);

    *array = (directory**) realloc( *array , (*length) * (sizeof(directory*)));
    *array[(*length)] = p;
    (*length)++;

}

int main(int argc , char** argv) {

    directory** array = NULL;

    int lenght = 0;

    while(true) {
        insertDir(&array, parameters.path, name , &lenght);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It fails on the third `realloc` with segmentation fault. Can you help me please?

Comment: You should never type cast the return from malloc/realloc/calloc in C.  Get in the habit early!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing the `realloc()`, you need to add 1 to the length, because you haven't incremented it yet.

```
*array = realloc( *array , (*length + 1) * (sizeof(directory*)));
```

You also need to change:

```
*array[(*length)] = p;
```

to:

```
(*array)[*length] = p;
```

because the subscripting operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator. See the C operator precedence table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). There's also no need for parentheses inside `[]`.

Comment: thanks, that was a mistake but its interesting that it still works the same way :/

Comment: It's not really working, you're causing undefined behavior. Anything can happen when you do that, including "seeming" to work for a while.

Comment: it fails even after correction... maybe the mistake isnt here

Comment: You're calling `insertDir`, but the function is named `insetrDir`. You should be getting an error about an undefined function.

Comment: oops, i didnt copy-paste that part, so it was just here... but thanks a lot for help.. i am going to continue analyzing my whole code :D

Comment: debugger points at this line " *array[(*length)] = p; " when program crash

Comment: What is the value of `*array` when that happens? What's the value of `*length`?

Comment: *length == 2 and it shows array as a variable that equals to first added directory. I really dont know because when i add: printf("meno : %s\n" , (*array[(*length)])->path); at the end it writes the name of second file too but in fact it never is in array

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `(*array)[*length]` indexing issue, you leave yourself wide open for several allocation failures with both `malloc` and `realloc`. First, and generally, always **validate** that your allocation succeeds. Enough said.

Next, with `realloc`, it is always better to reallocate using a `temporary` variable instead of your array. If there is a failure on reallocation, `realloc` returns `NULL` causing you to lose the address to `array` completely. This will cause the loss of all existing data. Instead, if you use a `tmp` pointer for reallocation, you have the ability to handle the failure in a graceful manner, and the ability to `free` the block of memory originally assigned to `array`.

Here is a bit more robust way to handle the allocations/reallocations. **Note:** you are left to code the response to a reallocation failure:

```
void insertDir (directory*** array, char *path, char *name, int *length)
{

    directory *p = malloc (sizeof *p);
    if (!p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    p->path = malloc (strlen (path) + 1);
    strcpy (p->path, path);

    p->name = malloc (strlen (name) + 1);
    strcpy(p->name, name);

    directory **tmp = realloc (*array, (*length + 1) * sizeof *tmp);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: struct reallocation failure.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *array = tmp;
    (*array)[*length] = p;
    (*length)++;

}
```